Struggling to come up with a formula for this coding problem
I was given a coding problem that basically sums up to for array size n filled with positive integers, find value v at position k such that v is the greatest possible value, no neighboring values have a difference greater than 1, and the sum of the array does not exceed a given amount m.
I could probably code a solution for this using an algorithm, but I ended up wasting a great deal of time trying to come up with a formula that could solve this for any set of variables in constant time. I feel it in my bones, there has to be some sort of relation that can describe this problem.
I ended up with an equation solving for the value v at k that basically goes:
$$
v = \frac{m+a+b}{n}
$$
Where $a = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and $b = \frac{(n-k-1)((n-k-1) + 1)}{2}$
Basically, if position k has value v, which is the largest it can have without violating the other two constraints, then we can think of the array as having v at every position, subtracting an incrementing amount for every k positions to the left of it and every n-k-1 positions to the right. That would look like this solving for m:
$$
m=vn-a-b
$$
This worked great, at least I think, until I realized that zero is technically not considered a positive integer. Each position in the array must have a value of at least 1. This cause all sorts of problems. For example, for an array such that n=4, m=4, and k=3 (zero indexed), my formula produces v=2. This makes sense in my original understanding, where the array looked like [0, 0, 1, 2], but since the minimum value for each position is 1, the array must be [1, 1, 1, 1], v=1.
My new thought process is that I would have to subtract n from m, but then how would this effect constants a and b? Whatever I have tried hasn't really worked and just breaks my function. Any help would be appreciated, this has been nagging me for a few days.

Do all the integers have to be distinct? If not, why does filling 1 in all positions not work?

Distinctness is not an issue. Essentially I am solving for v. In that specific example, [1, 1, 1, 1] is the correct solution, making v=1. I am trying to figure out how to alter my formula to satisfy this.

As @sudeep5221 was saying, can't you always make the solutions a bunch of 1's? I would guess that the problem needs to be altered so that we are forced to attain a sum equal to $m$

I'll edit my post to provide clarity @Igor

I'd first think about it in reverse: given $n,k,v,$ what is the smallest possible array sum? This is easy to compute (but needs some casewise logic for how far $k$ is from each end of the array, which determines whether you can get all the way down to 1s). Then you can try inverting the function (or just binary search for the largest acceptable $k$).

@Karl my question is whether this can be done in constant time.

It can! You can invert the function analytically. The binary search just might be easier to code (and is practically as fast as constant time, since the number of steps is just the bit-length of the result).
